# sqlite3: "IN" works, "NOT IN" doesn't

Tags: sqlite

This query works:

`select id from wagtailcore_pagerevision
  where id in (select live_revision_id as id from wagtailcore_page)`

This query produces no results:

`select id from wagtailcore_pagerevision
  where id not in (select live_revision_id as id from wagtailcore_page)`

(The difference is `in` *vs.* `not in`.)

... but I can very plainly see by inspection of the data that the result of the second query should be many hundreds of rows.

An index does exist on the `live_revision_id` column, and `id` of course is a primary key.

Comment: What do you expect the second one to return? Are there any id values in the pagerevision table that aren't present in that column of the page table?

Comment: There are about 600 entries in `wagtailcore_pagerevision` and 15 in `wagtailcore_page`.  The first query unsurprisingly returns 15 rows.  The second query should return about 585.